# How to insert the item back to UICollectionView in the same order as they were deleted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to insert the deleted item back to uicollectionview and they have to maintain the same indexPath when they were deleted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to undelete an object, first you would need to figure out which indexpath was it deleted from.

Then you can dequeue a 
`- dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and use insert

```
- insertItemsAtIndexPaths:
```

to insert it at the required indexpath.

Comment: thanks, but how to firgure out which indexpath it was deleted from. Since the index path for other cell would change when one cell is deleted, it seems hard to figure out.

Comment: Are you deleting the items yourself? If so then you can save indexPath accordingly. 
For example if you are showing foodItems [@"bread",@"milk",@"eggs",@"oil",@"butter"]. If you have deleted eggs, you would keep it's indexPath somewhere. And when needed you can insert it back to the same indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different approach would be in your model to have a `deleted` property. That way when you delete an object, you mark it as deleted and when you want to restore it you set it back to `false`. This way you will preserve the original order of the objects.